# handling username / password in cookie for login

Tags: cookies, authentication, session-cookies

Making a login script and I have the following cookies right now :

This is on every page, but expires on browser close.

```
session_name('Test_Login');
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.test.com', false, false);
session_start();
```

This is stores the username if a successful login happens.  When returning to the site it will fill out the username in the login form.

```
setcookie('Test_User', $_POST['username'], time()+365*24*60*60, '/', '.test.com', false, false);
```

This remembers the value of the 'remember me' option on the login form - true or false.

```
setcookie('Test_Remember', $_POST['rememberMe'], time()+365*24*60*60, '/', '.test.com', false, false);
```

This stores the user plain text password if they selected the remember me option above and lets them automatically login when visiting the site even after browser close within a day.  If this and user cookie are present it checks if valid and creates the user session variables again.

```
setcookie('Test_Pass', $_POST['password'], time()+24*60*60, '/', '.test.com', false, false);
```

Other things to consider are if you log out the session pass cookie is destroyed.

My problems : I md5 and salt the user password for storage in the database.  I actually never know the users pass.  Problem is with the remember option I am storing their password in plain view in the cookie.  What is the best way to store the pass in a cookie and it be useable in this fashion?  What is the standard of doing so?  Basically I just want this to act same as Facebook or any other login system.  If you tell it to remember you it does - so how do they store the info to log back in without doing so in plain text in the cookie?

Is it best practice to have a separate cookie (4) for this?  The session cookie makes sense, but is there not a more optimized way on my end to combine the other three?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple sources have pointed to http://jaspan.com/improved_persistent_login_cookie_best_practice as the best practice for my purposes.

Comment: This link now requires authentication. Click [here](https://gist.github.com/oleg-andreyev/9dcef18ca3687e12a071648c1abff782) to see a copy of the content.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't store the password in a cookie it's not a good practice and can lead to security issues (somebody could "steal" the cookie for example and get the user password).

Instead, once the user has been correctly authenticated once, you could save the sessionId in a cookie and on next visit the sessionId will be passed to the server which will be able to retrieve the session. For additional security store the IP address too and check that it is the same when reopening the session. You could also make your server sessions expire after 2 weeks for example.

To do this you need to use a cookie, not a session cookie (which is deleted once the browser is closed).
Check `session_set_cookie_params()` and give session cookie a lifetime.
See the PHP manual for more info: http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-lifetime

In the end, if you really want more security, you should definitely have a look at SSL.

Comment: I don't see how this would be any different.  User end has a sessionid stored in a cookie.  That validates against the same sessionid stored in the db. You are in the exact same boat and would be no different than storing the password instead.

Comment: If on the server you define that session is valid for 2 weeks only and if you also store the IP in the session, and compare it when logging, then it's definitely much safer than having the password in the cookie. Furthermore if you store the password in the cookie, and the user has the same password on different websites (which is nearly always the case) then this data is not only sensitive for your website but for all websites where he shares this password. You don't have this issue with cookies. If you want additional security, just use SSL.

Answer (score 1):

You should use session variables instead of storing the data in a cookie.

Here's an example in PHP

```
<?php

session_start();
$_SESSION['password'] = 'YOUR PASSWORD HERE';

//then you can reference the session variable in your code
echo $_SESSION['password'];

?>
```

You can set how long the sessions will stay for and the user cannot directly access the session variables because they are stored on the server. This is the way many secure login system works.

Comment: That has nothing to do with my question.  The session is deleted after browser close.  The whole purpose of my question is the best way to go about using a cookie to allow for auto-login (the remember feature) so if the browser is closed and they have that enabled the cookie can validate them, autologin, and restore session variables.